# Какой @WriteOperation для EnvironmentEndpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot

Кто нибудь знает, какой метод отвечает за обновление энвайронмента в EnvironmentEndpoint?

Вот этот урл:

POST /actuator/env

Spring boot actuator 2.5.+

Answer (score 0):

Нашелся.)

Это WritableEnvironmentEndpoint из библиотекаи actuator-cloud (вроде так)